# Importação de XML para tabelas Oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, pl-sql

.
Olá,

Preciso importar um arquivo XML para uma tabela oracle. Há diversos exemplos na internet, porém nenhum deles funcionou pra mim. Em geral, estou tendo o erro:

```
LPX-00210: expected '<' instead of '�'
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.LOAD_XML", line 16
```

Segue procedures:

### Exemplo XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<funcionarios>
<funcionario>
    <CodUsu>PRV120</CodUsu>
    <NomFunci>TESTE DA SILVA</NomFunci>
    <DataPosse>01/01/2001</DataPosse>
    <CodGerencia>67</CodGerencia>
    < --MUITO MAIS INFORMAÇÃO ... -->
</funcionario>
<funcionario>
    <CodUsu>PRV121</CodUsu>
    <NomFunci>TESTE DA SILVA1</NomFunci>
    <DataPosse>01/12/2001</DataPosse>
    <CodGerencia>67</CodGerencia>
    < --MUITO MAIS INFORMAÇÃO ... -->
</funcionario>
<funcionario>
    <CodUsu>PRV122</CodUsu>
    <NomFunci>TESTE DA SILVA2</NomFunci>
    <DataPosse>28/06/2001</DataPosse>
    <CodGerencia>67</CodGerencia>
    < --MUITO MAIS INFORMAÇÃO ... -->
</funcionario>
</funcionarios>
```

### Tabela que vai Armazenar o XML a ser lido

```
CREATE TABLE INFO_XML
(ID NUMBER,
DATA_ALTERACAO DATE,
CONTEUDO XMLTYPE)
```

### Importando XML para a tabela INFO_XML

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE load_xml ( p_id IN NUMBER,
p_filename IN VARCHAR2) AS
l_bfile BFILE := BFILENAME( 'XML_FILE', p_filename);
targetfile BFILE;
l_clob CLOB;
BEGIN

targetfile := l_bfile;

DBMS_LOB.createtemporary (l_clob, TRUE);

DBMS_LOB.fileopen(targetfile, DBMS_LOB.file_readonly);
DBMS_LOB.loadfromfile(l_clob, targetfile, DBMS_LOB.getlength(targetfile));
DBMS_LOB.fileclose(targetfile);

INSERT INTO INFO_XML (id, data_atualizacao, conteudo)
VALUES (p_id, sysdate, XMLTYPE.createXML(l_clob));

DBMS_LOB.freetemporary (l_clob);
END;
```

--Onde XML_FILE é o meu diretório criado no ORACLE indicando o caminho físico do .xml

### Chamada da Procedure load_xml

```
BEGIN
load_xml(p_id=>1, p_filename => 'Teste.xml');
END;
```

E então o erro que mencionei:

### Erro

```
ORA-31061: XDB error: XML event error
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
In line 1 of orastream:
LPX-00210: expected '<' instead of '�'
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.LOAD_XML", line 16
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Faz uma semana que não consigo progredir com esta tarefa, se alguém tiver alguma ideia será muito bem vinda.
Depois deste armazenamento, ainda vem a parte do extractvalue da coluna xmltype da tabela inserindo as strings das tags em uma outra tabela, mas acho desnecessário postar aqui sendo que nem consegui concluir essa primeira parte.

Obrigada,
Abs.

Comment: Tentou abrir este arquivo com outro programa que leia xml ?

Comment: Tentei sim Motta, mudei toda a procedure e funcionou. Encontrei vários erros durante a construção, mas já deu certo. Vou postar aqui o resultado para que, quem sabe, alguém possa utilizar. Obrigada!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.
Caros, 
Seguem a solução que eu encontrei. Caso alguém enfrente os mesmos problemas, pode se servir do exemplo.

```
PROCEDURE IMPORTA_XML AS

BEGIN

  -- INSERE NA TABELA INFO_XML O .XML INTEIRO EM UMA COLUNA XMLTYPE

  INSERT INTO INFO_XML (ID, DATA, CONTEUDO) VALUES
    ((SELECT ID+1 FROM INFO_XML WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM INFO_XML)),
    SYSDATE,
    XMLTYPE(BFILENAME('PPM_FILE_DIR', 'NomeXML.xml'), NLS_CHARSET_ID('WE8ISO8859P1')));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('INTEGRACAO_RH_'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDD')||'.XML INSERIDO EM INFO_XML');
  COMMIT;


  -- EXTRAI DA TABELA INFO_XML O ARQUIVO E LE COMO STRING SUAS TAGS RELACIONADAS ABAIXO.
  INSERT INTO VIEW_AQF (codUsu, NOMFUNCI, PRIMEIRONOME, NOMEMEIO, SOBRENOME, DSCEMAILPROPOS, CODCARGO,
    DSCCARGOPREVI, CODDIRETORIA, DIRETORIA, CODGERENCIA, GERENCIA, CODNUCLEO, NUCLEO, DATAPOSSEPREVI,
    NUMTEL2FUNCI, GERENTE, /*DATALTER,*/ INDATIVO)
    SELECT DISTINCT
    LOWER(EXTRACTVALUE (value(func), '/funcionario/codUsu')) codUsu,
    EXTRACTVALUE (value(func), '/funcionario/nomFunci') nomFunci,
    EXTRACTVALUE (value(func), '/funcionario/primeiroNome') primeiroNome,
    EXTRACTVALUE (value(func), '/funcionario/nomeMeio') nomeMeio,
    EXTRACTVALUE (value(func), '/funcionario/sobrenome') sobrenome,
    EXTRACTVALUE (value(func), '/funcionario/dscEmailPropos') dscEmailPropos,
    EXTRACTVALUE (value(func), '/funcionario/codCargo') codCargo,
    EXTRACTVALUE (value(func), '/funcionario/dscCargoPrevi') dscCargoPrevi,
    EXTRACTVALUE (value(func), '/funcionario/codDiretoria') codDiretoria,
    EXTRACTVALUE (value(func), '/funcionario/diretoria') diretoria,
    nvl(EXTRACTVALUE (value(func), '/funcionario/codGerencia'), 125) codGerencia,
    nvl(EXTRACTVALUE (value(func), '/funcionario/gerencia'), 'GTEST') gerencia,
    nvl(EXTRACTVALUE (value(func), '/funcionario/codNucleo'), 69) codNucleo,
    nvl(EXTRACTVALUE (value(func), '/funcionario/nucleo'), 'DTIJR') nucleo,
    EXTRACTVALUE (value(func), '/funcionario/dataPossePrevi') dataPossePrevi,
    EXTRACTVALUE (value(func), '/funcionario/numTel2Funci') numTel2Funci,
    EXTRACTVALUE (value(func), '/funcionario/gerente') gerente,
    --EXTRACTVALUE (value(func), '/funcionario/datAlter') datAlter,
    EXTRACTVALUE (value(func), '/funcionario/indAtivo') indAtivo
    FROM INFO_XML, TABLE (XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(conteudo, '/funcionarios/funcionario'))) func
    WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM INFO_XML);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('IMPORTADO PARA VIEW_AQF EM:'||SYSDATE);
  COMMIT;

END;
```

Onde:

- PPM_FILE_DIR = Diretório criado no Banco;
- NomeXML.xml = Nome do .xml que deve estar no caminho criado do diretório;
- NLS_CHARSET_ID('WE8ISO8859P1') = Encoding do meu XML é ISOLatino, então seu Id.

=)